# tkinter: Dynamic label to show value from sensor

Tags: python, dynamic, tkinter, label

The following code is what i have right now. I also tried it with the given solutions in the interweb like here [Link1](http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_labels.php).

But this seems too complicated for a simple function like mine, i want to have more "elegant" code.
That's what i have:

```
.
.
box = Tk()
box.title('TCS3490')
box.geometry('200x180')

labelLux = Label(master=box, text='Lux=')
labelLux.place(x=5, y=5, width=60, height=30)

labelLuxValue = Label(master=box, text=str(dev.calcLux()))
labelLuxValue.place(x=50, y=50, width=100, height=30)
labelLuxValue.after(10, labelLuxValue.config(text = str(dev.calcLux()))  

box.mainloop()
```

It puts a value once in that label but not again. 
dev.calcLux() returns a float value
Why?

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that the after line is executed just once, you need a recursive function:

```
def update():
    labelLuxValue.config(text = str(dev.calcLux())
    labelLuxValue.after(100, update)

update()
```

See for example:
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2006-April/000704.html

Comment: Your answr would be more valuable if it contained some explanation as well, rather than *just* code. Just a suggestion!

Comment: Hi Eric, if you had checked my link, you would have seen, that i already tried that.
I want to understand, why just the "after"-function by itself doesn't work.
I also came across your link already.

Comment: It works: it waits 10ms then update the label. But why should it repeat itself? If you just want to say that you don't like the current definition of after, you can. You can also edit the source code of tkinter...

Comment: Ok, now i see, why it has to be in that recursive function.
But what happens, if you have 2 recursive functions that need to work parallel? I would say as soon as the program is in one loop, it never will leave it.

Comment: Or probably one had to put all functions in one global update function.

Comment: Yes, that would be the correct way of updating multiple labels.